# How to submit form after login using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I am a writing an application to view the schedule, but I have a problem: I can not grab the url I want. Here is my code.
   i have solved the prolem.

```
Connection.Response res=Jsoup.connect("http://regis.agu.edu.vn/default.aspx?page=dangnhap")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();
            Document doc=res.parse();
            Document Login=Jsoup.connect("http://regis.agu.edu.vn/Default.aspx")
                    .data("__EVENTTARGET","")
                    .data("__EVENTARGUMENT","")
                    .data("__VIEWSTATE",doc.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ucDangNhap$txtTaiKhoa","dth135165")
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ucDangNhap$txtMatKhau","01694215528")
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ucDangNhap$btnDangNhap","Ðăng Nhập")
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .post();
            t2=doc.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val();
            Connection.Response testRequest = Jsoup.connect("http://regis.agu.edu.vn/default.aspx?page=thoikhoabieu&sta=0")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .followRedirects(false) // <-- did the trick
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .execute();
            Document res1=testRequest.parse();
            Document tkb=Jsoup.connect("http://regis.agu.edu.vn/default.aspx?page=thoikhoabieu&sta=0")
                    .data("__EVENTTARGET","")
                    .data("__EVENTARGUMENT","")
                    .data("__LASTFOCUS","")
                    .data("__VIEWSTATE",res1.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").val())
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ddlChonNHHK","20161")
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ddlLoai","0")
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ddlTuan","Tuần 09 [Từ 10/10/2016 -- Đến 16/10/2016]")
                    .data("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$btnDt","Tuần Đầu")
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .post();
```

Here is a screenshot of [params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hMB2.png).

Comment: `I can not grab the url I want.` What is the error/exception that you receive?

Comment: thank you. I have solved the problem

Comment: Then please write an answer yourself (for other users faced with similar problems) or reference an answer on Stackoverflow that helped you to resolve your issue.